# How to convert textbox value to date format in firefox and Internet explorer using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, calendar, datetimepicker

I have textbox( id='txtCalendarSeventh' ) which have a calendar control associated with it. On Selecting any date from calendar I get the value in textbox in the format-  Apr-21-2014   .

I am using the following javascript code-

```
 var dateresult = document.getElementById('txtCalendarSeventh').value;
    var d = new Date(dateresult);
    alert(d);
```

This code works fine in chrome and dispalys correct value of date. But in firefox or internet explorer it is showing Nan.Nan.Nan etc instead of correct date.

Comment: look at the available methods u can set the date using the `Date` object in JS.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Apr-21-2014" is not a valid date string, although some browsers may recognise it. "Apr 21 2014" should work though, for example.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is use the ISO format: YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

For example:

```
new Date('2011-04-11')
```

or

```
new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:00')
```

For more Info: MDN | Date

Edit:

For old Internet Explorer compatibility (IE versions less than 9 do not support ISO format in Date constructor), you should split datetime string representation to it's parts and then you can use constructor using datetime parts, e.g.: new Date('2011', '04' - 1, '11', '11', '51', '00')

Note that the number of the month must be 1 less.